# Folder `/run/user/$(id -u)` does not exist

Tags: raspbian, systemd

I am running raspian (Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7+) on a headless raspberry pi (3B+), and I have just realized that my *unprivileged* user (uid 1001) does not get its `/run/user/1001/` folder at boot.

What could be the problem here?

I noticed that the pi user (uid 1000) gets its `/run/user/1000/` folder at login as expected, so I rule out a system-wide issue here. I am wondering whether the unprivileged user is missing from some important group?

*pi* is member of: pi adm dialout cdrom audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi

*my_user* is member of: my_user audio users docker

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure, just an idea: is `/run/user/$(id -u)` always created even an empty directory if the user does not use any sockets or have to store pids?

Comment: Gut feel is that nothing has run under that user based on the notes in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162900/what-is-this-folder-run-user-1000

Comment: It does if I `ssh` into my Pi using another user, but vanishes when I disconnect, so presumably you are not running anything which requires it.